# Lotus Designer crashes everytime I open the subform category

Tags: lotus-notes

Every time I double click the subform category my Designer / Client crashes.  I have done the following without success:

- run a fixup on the database
- run a compact -c on the database
- reinstalled the client and designer

The NSD does not contain any relevant info (run it through LDD).

It happens is not specific to one machine.  I can edit a subform and save it with no problem, as long as I double click on the subform from the left hand side menu structure.  I'm running 8.5.3.

Comment: Is it a crash or hang? If a crash, post the stack. If it mentions at the top it crashed in the eclipse part, Open the error/trace logs in workspace\logs folder. Then post the first SEVERE error you find. .. That aside, removing the workspace folder (back it up) can recover issues, but you may loose the ability to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked NSDs but nothing of interest came up.  I ran a fixup and a compact - still same issue.  Then I went through and deleted the subforms from the left hand side menu and then copied the design elements back in.  This was the only way I was able to access the subforms as the client was crashing if I double clicked the subform category.  All good now.